# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name 'flags' " while importing flags from Cleverhans.compat in Python

Tags: python-3.x, cleverhans

I am having a problem while playing the following code given as example in [Cleverhans Library](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans_tutorials/mnist_tutorial_jsma.py) :

The problem is on Line # 18 . When it plays it gives out an import error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'flags'
```

I have tried to see in the help and there is also no flags function listed there.

```
from cleverhans.compat import flags
```

This should work by simply importing the module and giving no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

If any such error appears then its due to the problem in the way you have set your environment to work in .

If the dependencies are perfectly aligned then there comes no such error.

Thanks :)

P.S. If you find such error while running your code in Cleverhans then drop me a message . I'll be happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

To anyone that needs a solution: 
replace `from cleverhans.compat import flags` with `from tensorflow.python.platform import flags`

Comment: i did try that too . This error gets resolved but there are other multiple errors that come . Anyways thanks for contributing :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pycharm, maybe you should open all the project 'cleverhans-master', and right-click on it，select mark directory as---source root. And it could be imported normally.